# How to retrieve data from database using Ajax and OOP php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, oop

I am going to develop web page with ajax and php. but there is problem in my get_data_in_table function. it will show data in a table structure. but it shows error when i run this code. others are working properly. it shows error in while loop. but i am unable to find any issue.

```
    class get_data()

    {
     public function get_data_in_table($query){
            $output='';
            $result=  $this->Getdata($query);
            $output.='
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tr>
                    <th>Countty</th>
                    <th>Airline Name</th>
                    <th>Arrival Time</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Comment</th>


    </tr>';
            while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $output .='

                        <tr>
    <td>'.$row->country.'</td>
    <td>'.$row->air_line.'</td>
        <td>'.$row->arrival_time.'</td>
          <td>'.$row->status.'</td>
              <td>'.$row->comment.'</td>


    </tr>';


            }
            $output.='</table>';
            return $output;
                    }
?>
```

Comment: okaaay, what error is it showing?

Comment: Where is your ajax code?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?>', expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\xampp\htdocs\air-pos\svr\plane-retrive.php on line 56

this is the error

Comment: where are you creating the `$query` ?

Comment: $query create from ajax page is ok. and properly work. i think problem should be concatenation.

Comment: code you shared does not have any `?>`

Comment: please provide your ajax code also. And can you please highlight the line no. 56

Comment: line 56 php closing tag.
Here is the ajax code.     
  
:[link] (<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        load_data();
        function load_data(){
            var action ="Load";
            $.ajax({
                url:"svr/action.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{action:action},
                success:function(data){
                    $('#panel-body').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });

Comment: The **closing brace** of the class is not present in the code you have shared. You closed the function body but the class body is still open.

Comment: MIssing close brace in class

Comment: @sinha that is final it is a line 56.

Comment: @JYoThI that is error. missing close brace in class

Answer (score 2):

I guess I found it:

```
  class get_data()

    {
     public function get_data_in_table($query){
            $output='';
            $result=  $this->Getdata($query);
            $output.='
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tr>
                    <th>Countty</th>
                    <th>Airline Name</th>
                    <th>Arrival Time</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Comment</th>


    </tr>';
            while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $output .='

                        <tr>
    <td>'.$row->country.'</td>
    <td>'.$row->air_line.'</td>
        <td>'.$row->arrival_time.'</td>
          <td>'.$row->status.'</td>
              <td>'.$row->comment.'</td>


    </tr>';


            }
            $output.='</table>';
            return $output;
                    }
} // This was missing
    ?>
```

Comment: Yes. that is a problem

Comment: well great then! Have fun